# Asp.net webservice with SSL returns 404

Tags: asp.net, web-services, ssl, http-status-code-404

The web service returns **404** while used over **https** otherwise it works fine. The setup is as follows...

web.config:

```
<services>
  <service name="WebAppSSL.astLogin">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="webHttpBinding"                  
              contract="WebAppSSL.astLogin" />
    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpsBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="secureHttpBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>    
</bindings>
```

The svc code is...

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class astLogin
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public string welcome(string name)
    {
        return "Hi " + name;
    }
}
```

The trace shows this message...

```
<Description>Failed to lookup a channel to receive an incoming message. Either the endpoint or the SOAP action was not found.</Description>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for reference if someone is here...

The solution is to use static wsdl & xsd files; at least it worked for me. My setup is...

1. ASP.net Web Application
2. Web Forms WCF is part of the the project
3. SSL (either self issued or CA issued)

Foremost and important: enable webservice trace; [How to enable trace.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702726(v=vs.110).aspx)
A trace file can be viewed by executing `svctraceviewer.exe` from VS Command; there you would need to select the trace file
as mentioned in your **web.config** file.

You need to make sure that SSL is linked to the website and activated. [SSL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556232(v=vs.110).aspx)

Change web.config; sample config elements are...

```
  <system.serviceModel> 
    <services>
      <service name="WebAppSSL.astLogin" behaviorConfiguration="astLoginSrvcBehavior">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding"                  
                  behaviorConfiguration="astLoginEpntBehavior"
                  contract="WebAppSSL.astLogin">
            <identity>
              <dns value="" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint> 
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>        
        <binding name="secureHttpBinding" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>     
      <endpointBehaviors>        
        <behavior name="astLoginEpntBehavior">
          <webHttp faultExceptionEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"  /> 
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="astLoginSrvcBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata 
            httpsGetEnabled="true" 
            externalMetadataLocation="astLogin.wsdl"
            />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

In the **web.config** file refer to element `<serviceBehaviors><behavior><serviceMeradata>`, the property **externalMetadataLocation** will be used to point to static wsdl file. For sure it is a tiring process for large application and any change in service file's structure requires to repeat the process for that service.

To generate wsdl & xsd file:

Run your application to open service uri
    'http://webapplication-domain-name/service-name.svc'
You will get the page content like...
    [image]

Click on the **svcutil.exe** link and you will be shown the xml like...

```
    <wsdl:definitions name="astLogin" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
        <wsdl:import namespace="" location="https://localhost/WebAppSSL/astLogin.svc?wsdl=wsdl0"/>
        <wsdl:types/>
        <wsdl:service name="astLogin"/>
    </wsdl:definitions>
```

Copy url with **?wsdl** i.e. *https://localhost/WebAppSSL/astLogin.svc?wsdl=wsdl0* and paste into new tab or page
You will get the WSDL file like...

```
    <wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="/Imports">
            <xsd:import schemaLocation="https://localhost/WebAppSSL/astLogin.svc?xsd=xsd0"/>
            <xsd:import schemaLocation="https://localhost/WebAppSSL/astLogin.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/><xsd:import schemaLocation="https://localhost/WebAppSSL/astLogin.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebAppSSL.Models"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="astLogin_DoWork_InputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="DoWork"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="astLogin_DoWork_OutputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="DoWorkResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="astLogin">
        <wsdl:operation name="DoWork">
        <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="urn:astLogin/DoWork" message="astLogin_DoWork_InputMessage"/>
        <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="urn:astLogin/DoWorkResponse" message="astLogin_DoWork_OutputMessage"/>
    </wsdl:operation>   
    </wsdl:definitions>
```

In the WSDL file look for section `<xsd:import>`, copy url of `schemaLocation` and paste in new tab or page
(you need to do it for all the imports, except the schemaLocation which is referring to *namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"* do once for the application.

The XSD file *(when I say file, I mean you would need to either copy/paste or save page as filename.wsdl or filename.xsd)* may look like...

```
    <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebAppSSL.Models">
    <xs:complexType name="Elogin">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CompanyReqAuthentication" type="xs:boolean"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ErrorCode" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ErrorMessage" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="TokenID" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="UserReqAuthentication" type="xs:boolean"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="Elogin" nillable="true" type="tns:Elogin"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Now you have WSDL and XSD files. In both the files replace **'https://localhost/WebAppSSL/'** (will be different for you) with **https://fqdn/**
Not all the XSD file will refer to your dev machine URL, the reason is that XSD is referred only when underlying function is referring
to a model/class for data exchange.

That's it.

Credits:
 
 https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/166246/Error-There-was-no-endpoint-listening-at
 http://www.mytechtip.com/2012/09/static-wsdl-with-imported-xml-schema-in.html